# Admin can't delete users. Ruby on Rails 3 - Michael Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I'm following Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial by Michael Hartl. I'm stuck on chapter 10) Updating, Showing and Deleting Users. On 10.4.2 where you have to create an admin and have the option to delete the user, the link doesn't work (when I click delete).
I'm using ruby v2.1.3 and rails v4.1.6
Here is the code:

_user.html.erb

```
<li>
 <%= gravatar_for user, :size => 30 %>
 <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? %> |
   <%= link_to "delete", user, :method => :destroy, :confirm => "You sure?", :title => "Delete #    {user.name}" %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

users_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if current_user?(@user)
    redirect_to users_path, notice: "You can't destroy yourself."
  else
    @user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end
end
```

On my localhost:3000/users I have the following example:

```
test | delete
Pearl Hyatt | delete
etc.
```

After clicking the delete link, it should delete the user, insteed it goes to his/her profile and does nothing.
Any suggestions would be welcomed!!

Comment: Check for errors in your JS files, for example in your browser's error console.

Comment: Doh!! That was embarrasing, hadn't jquery called on my document. Anyway, I called jquery and now it redirects me home page but the user still exist.

Comment: Show relevant part of your application log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem. After calling jquery (my fault) and changed the link:

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, :method => :destroy, :confirm => "You sure?", :title => "Delete #{user.name}" %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?", :title => "Delete #{user.name}" %>
```

The link started working ok, with both flashes messages and the delete action ok.
Thanks for your kindly help anyway.